# Objective-C clang-format on a Macro block and align args

Tags: objective-c, clang-format

I'm fairly new to using clang-format and am having trouble formatting macro blocks that contain args; for example, React Native has a `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD` that produces a method with args. However this messes up most formatting options and the output comes out like the following:

```c
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(preferencesSetBool
                  : (NSString *)key boolValue
                  : (BOOL)boolValue resolver
                  : (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter
                  : (RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
  [[RNFBPreferences shared] setBooleanValue:key boolValue:boolValue];
  resolve([NSNull null]);
}
```

As you can see above the arg names are not matching up and are on different lines.

This is the format I'm ideally trying to achieve:

```c
  RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(
    preferencesSetBool : (NSString *) key
    boolValue          : (BOOL) boolValue
    resolver           : (RCTPromiseResolveBlock) resolve
    rejecter           : (RCTPromiseRejectBlock) reject
  ) {
    [[RNFBPreferences shared] setBooleanValue:key boolValue:boolValue];
    resolve([NSNull null]);
  }
```

Would this even be possible with clang-format? I've looked at `MacroBlockBegin` in my format file and tried fiddling with that and other options but can't seem to make much work.

If anyone could help me out or point me in the right direction that'd be great, thanks!